# Matching lists indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists,they has same elements.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If I write this:

```
a[::]==b[::]
>>>True
```

So that means all of elements indexes are equal. But I want to shuffle *b* till *b*'s indexes are different than *a*'s.

> I tried this:

```
import random
while a[::]==b[::]:
    random.shuffle(b)
```

I thought it will shuffle *b* till all of the indexes are different,but its not what I expected.All the time at least one element has same index.What can I do ?

Comment: Is it possible that `b` could be `[9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

`a[::] == b[::]` -- or simply `a == b` -- checks to see whether *all* the elements are equal, which is why your `while` is ending (probably on the very first step).

You want something different, namely that *none* of them are equal, IOW that `not any` are equal.

We can use `any` and `zip` to implement this condition:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> import random
>>> while any(x==y for x,y in zip(a,b)):
...     random.shuffle(b)
...     
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b
[6, 5, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3]
```

Comment: what is _zip_ and _any_ excatly? I didnt know that methods before.And can you write it step by step, not all of the things in while loop. eg: `for x,y in zip(a,b)`
                     `if any(x==y)`: ...

Comment: I wouldn't advise running this on a one element list though :p

Comment: @DSM can you write it please?

Comment: @domain12 the documentation for `any` and `zip` is well explained in the Python documentation - it'll take you 5 minutes to read that instead of asking clarification from the answerer :)

Comment: @domain12 also - worth considering infinite loop cases... given `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 3, 3]`... given your problem statement, it's not solvable...

Answer (score 0):

`a[::] == b[::]` checks that *all* the indices are equal. You want to keep shuffling as long as [*any*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) index is equal. Which is to say:

```
while any(a[i] == b[i] for i in xrange(len(a)):
    random.shuffle(b)
```